# "Maximum update depth exceeded" when using Private react-router Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've implemented my own Private react-router route following [this article.](https://ui.dev/react-router-v5-protected-routes-authentication/)

I want to redirect to `/sign-in` if the user object returned from `useProvideAuth` is null.

```
const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
  const { children, path, ...rest } = props;

  const { user } = useProvideAuth();
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) => {
        return user ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    ></Route>
  );
};
```

I'm getting a `Maximum update depth exceeded` error when I use `PrivateRoute`. I've set up a codesandbox to demonstrate.

https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-paper-u9q86

Thanks

Comment: "I want to redirect to /sign-in if the user object returned from useProvideAuth is null." Then you probably should **not** redirect to "/login" then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had quick look at sandbox code. Setup of `PrivateRoute` component is fine but issue is in the way routes are composed. They should be composed within `<Switch>` component of `react-router-dom`.

Since, `<Switch>` is missing, both routes defined are being rendered. And each time `/` route is rendered, PrivateRoute component redirects user to `/sign-in` and this process continues in loop thereby exceeding javascript stack size.

If you update Routes component to have routes enclosed in `Switch`, it will work:

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/sign-in">
          <SignIn />
        </Route>
        <PrivateRoute path="/">
          <Home />
        </PrivateRoute>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Please note that `Switch` should be imported from `react-router-dom` package.

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-bush-p591h

**NOTE:**

Other thing I noticed is login route is defined as `/sign-in` whereas in PrivateRoute component, user is being redirected to `/login` in case user is not authorized. Both these routes should be in sync.

Comment: @DrewReese That was because of `/login` route being incorrect in `PrivateRoute` component. Endpoint defined for it, is `/sign-in`. I have shared working sandbox in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another mistake you can make is wrapping the login route with the Protected Route. i.e

```
<PrivateRoute path="/login">
        <Login />
</PrivateRoute>
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31797902)